# Post-Job Checkout Hanging in Azure DevOps Pipelines

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, pipeline, repo

When I submit a job to my self hosted agent, the job will run, however at the end of the job the post-job checkout is hanging for like 12 minutes or so before the job completes and I am not sure why.

I have noticed that I get this behavior even when I don't checkout any repo as part of the pipeline. Any thoughts on what could be causing this behavior?

I'm using Self-hosted agents. I have also noticed that some agents run much faster than others.

Comment: I've noticed that sometimes pages don't refresh immediately, so maybe try `CTRL-F5` to force the refresh? Or maybe it was a temporary issue on Azure DevOps? See https://status.dev.azure.com/_history

Comment: could you share the pipeline code ?

Comment: Share the logs of the pipeline and of your hosted agent